# How to use Displaydns operation on a remote PC

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, remote-access, ipconfig

Is there a way to use the following command from a remote PC by its name or IP?

```
ipconfig /displaydns [IP/computer name]
```

Comment: you can use psexec to connect to cmd.exe on the remote system. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) if remote computer allows it.

```
psexec \\ip.ip.ip.ip ipconfig /displaydns
```

If you would get response "access denied" then you may try

```
cmdkey.exe /add:<RemoteMachineName> /user:<usernameOnRemoteMachine> /pass:<password>
psexec \\ip.ip.ip.ip ipconfig /displaydns
```

if it will fail too then follow steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103682)
 on remote computer to allow `psexec` connections

Comment: It works fine. Just trying to add the output to a file and it doesn't work. I added "> 1.txt" after displaydns but it doesn't create the file

Comment: @ehh Try `psexec "\\ip.ip.ip.ip ipconfig /displaydns" >.\1.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't help but just find it, the file is created on the remote PC, I need it to be created on the caller PC. Is it possible?

Comment: @ehh Could you try [these](http://serverfault.com/questions/33131/capturing-output-of-remote-process-from-sysinternals-psexec) suggestions.